# How do I open an file in AVR Studio?

Tags: avr, i2c, avr-studio4

I have two ATMEGA88 (master and slave) working correctly by sending a test[] via I2C.

Working enviroment: AVR Studio using C.

What I need is to allow the master be able to send a indicated file such as mydoc.txt to the slave.

Should I be using another application to build the UI? How can I connect a different IDE and make it work? Any pro? Or sample code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to send a file from one micro-controller to another, the master must be able to read the file from somewhere. If the file is small enough, you could bundle it into the the program code. The easier way to do this will be to convert the binary content into a C array.

If the file can't fit into the micro-controllers flash, one solution would be to use an external memory device. Another solution would be the master controller to communicate through RS-232 with a desktop PC to read the file.

AVR Studio is only used for programming and debugging. The actual action happens inside the microcontrollers.

Comment: more specific to say is how we make desktop pc to read file and give to master through RS-232, if the target file is too big!
Thanks

Comment: It would be better not to build a UI yourself, but to use an existing application. For example you could use HyperTerminal with zmodem or xmodem protocol to transfer files. You would need to implement the protocol at the microcontroller as well. Xmodem is easy to implement and you probably will be able to find source code at the web.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, thanks  kgiannakakis
According to my search, HyperTerminal probably will be the easy way to solve this question.
Labview might be another approach to achieve this project.